# trying saving State of Toggle button in recycleview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, sharedpreferences, togglebutton

I have a RecycleView and I want to save the state of it when user exist the app through Shared Preferences. My problem which i Couldn't solve it for 4 days is,  when I chick the Toggle button and  exit the App< when reopening it i find all Togglebuttons in the recycleview got checked , not only the specific one which i checked and Vice versa with unchecking

Togglebutton in xml

```
 <ToggleButton

                android:gravity="start"
                android:layout_width="24dp"
                android:layout_height="24dp"
                android:background="@drawable/check"
                android:textOn=""
                android:textOff=""
                android:id="@+id/ToggleHeartID"
                android:paddingLeft="20dp"
                android:onClick="Toggle"
                android:layout_margin="20dp"
                android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"

                />
```

this is my Adapter class which I handle the toggle button in it:

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

ItemClickListener mItemClickListener;
ArrayList<StoryModelM> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
public Context context;




MyAdapter(ArrayList<StoryModelM> arrayList){
    this.arrayList=arrayList;
}

@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false);

    return new  MyViewHolder(view);

}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder( MyViewHolder holder, int position) {

    holder.Listindex.setText(arrayList.get(position).getTitleModel());
   holder.ListContent.setText(arrayList.get(position).getContentModel());

    Context context =holder.itemView.getContext();

    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("tgpref1",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    boolean tgpref = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("tgpref",true);


    if (tgpref){
       holder.toggleButton.setChecked(true);
    }else {
       holder.toggleButton.setChecked(false);
    }


}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return arrayList.size();
}
public  class  MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
    TextView Listindex;
  TextView ListContent;
    ToggleButton toggleButton;




    public MyViewHolder(final View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        final Context context = itemView.getContext();




        Listindex =(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.TextViewTitleID);
       ListContent = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.TextViewContentID);
        toggleButton =(ToggleButton)itemView.findViewById(R.id.ToggleHeartID);



        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
       toggleButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {
               int position = getAdapterPosition();

                   if (toggleButton.isChecked()) {



                       Animation plus = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(v.getContext(), R.anim.pulse);
                       toggleButton.startAnimation(plus);
                      SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("tgpref1", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                       SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
                       editor.putBoolean("tgpref", true);

                       editor.commit();



                   }


                   else {
                       SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = itemView.getContext().getSharedPreferences("tgpref1", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                       SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

                       editor.putBoolean("tgpref", false);
                       editor.commit();



                   }


           }
       });





    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (mItemClickListener!=null)
            mItemClickListener.onItemClick(itemView, getAdapterPosition(), getItemId());


        }




}

public void setFilter(ArrayList<StoryModelM> newList) {

    arrayList= new ArrayList<>();
    arrayList.addAll(newList);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
public void setmItemClickListener(ItemClickListener itemClickListener ){
    this.mItemClickListener= itemClickListener;
}




public interface ItemClickListener {
    void onItemClick(View view, int position , long id );

}

public interface ToggleInterface {
    void toggleonClick(View view);
}


@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return position;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Yes, because all your rows have same value from the `SharedPreferences`: `boolean tgpref = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("tgpref",true);`

If you want to save the value for each row, you should save the boolean value with the key + position like: 
`editor.putBoolean("tgprefAtPosition0", true);`

After that, you can get the boolean value for each position like: 
`boolean tgpref = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("tgprefAtPosition"+ position ,true);`

Answer (score 0):

The answer given by Kingfisher Phuoc is not fully correct, because we have to keep in mind that the Arraylist will be updated after we filter the objects.
Let's imagine that each tooglebutton of each item of the recyclerview is identified by its position(tgprefAtPosition0,tgprefAtPosition1,tgprefAtPosition2,....).Eg.:After we do a search of the item2(which teorically would contain tgprefAtPosition1) this one will pop up in the first position of the recyclerview and therefore the tooglebutton is identified by tgprefAtPosition0 and not by tgprefAtPosition1. So what we need to do is identify them unequivocally in order to distinguish before filtering and after filtering(it's almost like if you had 2 recyclerview, and you want to identify an item even though it can be in different positions in the 2 recyclerview). I would suggest to identify them by the title for instance(something not related to numbers)...here's how:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
StoryModelM s = arraylist.get(position);
String title = s.getTitle();
//...

Context context =holder.itemView.getContext();
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("tgpref1",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
boolean tgpref = sharedPreferences.getBoolean(title,false);//all tooglebuttons unchecked

if (tgpref){ //binding each button to its value when building recyclerview 
    holder.toggleButton.setChecked(true);
}else {
    holder.toggleButton.setChecked(false);
 }
}
//...
public String getTitle(int pos){
   return this.arraylist.get(pos).getTitle();
}
 //...
public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
    ToggleButton toggleButton;
    
  public MyViewHolder(final View itemView) {
      super(itemView);

      final Context context = itemView.getContext();
      toggleButton =(ToggleButton)itemView.findViewById(R.id.ToggleHeartID);

      toggleButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {

       //...
           int position = getAdapterPosition();

             if (toggleButton.isChecked()) {
//after we click on the button of a specific item,if it turns true we save that boolean value so when we re-open the app that button will still have the same state
                    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("tgpref1", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
                    editor.putBoolean(getTitle(position), true);
                    editor.commit();
                    //...
             }else{
                    //...
                    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = itemView.getContext().getSharedPreferences("tgpref1", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
                    editor.putBoolean(getTitle(position), false);
                    editor.commit();
               }

    //...
    }
 }
```

You can also set the image of the tooglebutton to something you like inside of each condition to leave it more professional...that's basically it :)